# Silverlight - Bing Maps Control - Clustering of Pushpins

Tags: maps, bing-maps, cluster-analysis, markers, pushpin

I use the Bing Maps Control and try to cluster Pushpins which are near together on the screen.
Do somebody know a finished Solution for this ?
I only can find solutions for the AJAX Control:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/keithkin/archive/2009/03/07/customizing-pushpin-clustering-with-virtual-earth-map-control-api.aspx

My Approach:
Basically i loop through all items, determine the Size of them and add them to the layer or not.

That works principally, but if i want to add 1.000.000 items, i create 1.000.000 UIElements to get the Size of them and that is really slow (And needs much memory!) Is there any other approach ?

Comment: But you'll _always_ need the number of items in memory that you want to display; I don't get the question...

Answer (score 0):

I have not used it yet personally, but I have found a 3 part article concerning *Server-Side* Clustering, which for over 5000 data points would be the better choice than client side.

http://jkebeck.wordpress.com/?s=cluster

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this article - also not tried it. I need to implement client-side clustering in Bing Maps Silverlight so looks like a good fit

http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/11/pushpin-clustering-with-the-windows-phone-7-bing-map-control/